# Convert NominalDiffTime to Real

Tags: haskell

In the documentation for [Data.Time.Clock](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.1/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t%3aNominalDiffTime) I see this:

> Conversion functions will treat it as seconds. It has a precision of 10^-12 s

What function will turn that `NominalDiffTime` into a `Double`? No luck [hoogling it](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=NominalDiffTime+-%3E+Double)

Answer (score 18):

You need to pay more attention to the list of instances for the type.  One of the listed instances is `Real NominalDiffTime`.  This allows you to use `realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) :: a -> b` to convert to `Double`, since `Double` is an instance of `Fractional`.

Since `NominalDiffTime` has a `Real` instance, and `Double` has a `Fractional` instance, you can use `realToFrac` as if it had the type signature `NominalDiffTime -> Double`.  Of course, `realToFrac` is more polymorphic than that, and so you might need to give it hints exactly what types you want to convert sometimes.  But it certainly is capable of that conversion, if it can figure out the types.

Comment: Could you explain why a `Fractional` is appropriate here, and how to convert that to a `Double`? This is probably elementary stuff...

Comment: `Fractional` is just a type class.  There is no "convert `Fractional` to `Double`" because they aren't even the same sort of thing.  `Double` is a type.  `Fractional` is a property a type can have.  It's kind of like asking how you'd convert a horse to running. Running is a thing a horse can do, but it doesn't stop being a horse to do so.

Comment: @Carl, it makes perfect sense to ask whether a function of type `Fractional a => a -> Double` exists, which would be a conversion from a fractional to a double.

Answer (score 4):

[You can hoogle it allright](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Real+a%2C+Real+b%29+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b), just need to make the signature a bit more general. In this case, you know both types approximate real numbers, so that's what I'd search. Admittedly, this would have required some like in this case: the equally reasonably `(RealFloat a, RealFloat b) => a -> b` query wouldn't have given you the correct `realToFrac` right at 2nd spot.

But it's always worth to try some more general ways a function you need might be defined. Normally, if some type has instances of standard classes then the module won't bother much to also export specialised versions of the same functionality.

`realToFrac` in particular is something of a joker that works very often for numeric conversions, perhaps 2nd-most common after `fromIntegral`. (Though, honestly, I don't like this function too much because mathematically, "converting a real number to a fraction" [is pretty horrible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number), but oh well...)

Comment: Don't think of it as converting a real, but as converting some number along the real axis.  :)   But I agree, the Haskell conversion are not nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since `time-1.9.1` you can use [`nominalDiffTimeToSeconds`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/src/Data.Time.Clock.Internal.NominalDiffTime.html#nominalDiffTimeToSeconds) from `Data.Time.Clock` module:

```
nominalDiffTimeToSeconds :: NominalDiffTime -> Pico

Get the seconds in a NominalDiffTime.
```